# How do I get emoticons to show as images rather than text in SMS messages?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, motorola-droid-x

I've got a Motorola Droid X running Android 2.2 (Froyo), and when sending and receiving SMS/text messages in the default text messaging program, I don't see the Android emoticon images in the message.  I instead only see the text representing that emoticon.  For instance, I only see `:-)` rather than the smiley emoticon image.

Is there a setting somewhere that turns that feature on or off?

Comment: See also this question that's from someone trying to turn the robot emoticons off http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-emoticons-in-the-standard-android-sms-app no one's found the setting there yet but if they do it could help you out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and was not able to find any way to do this on a stock device. However [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=8676526) is a link for you root users that allows you to remove the stock emoticons and replace them with standard ones, I'm sure it will let you do other emoticons as well.