# Disable smileys in SMS

Tags: htc-desire, sms, cyanogenmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to change the emoticons in the standard android sms app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-emoticons-in-the-standard-android-sms-app)

I find graphical emoticons (smileys) seriously distracting. How do I disable them?

My device is a rooted HTC Desire running CyanogenMod 7.10 RC, but I don't think that'll limit the applicability of the answers.

Comment: I think "disable" can sort of be equated to "change to text", and the answers in that question actually talk about disabling them. The summary is "no" on the stock app, and you can [track this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3448) on the Android issue tracker regarding it.

Comment: @eldarerathis - hmm, while it IS true that Handcent allows you to do this, it is a truly awful looking SMS app (and that's even after customisation). If you answer with your second comment, that'll have to do I suppose.