# Disable emoticons

Tags: sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to change the emoticons in the standard android sms app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-emoticons-in-the-standard-android-sms-app)

How do I disable those green smilies in the SMS app? I am using Cyanogen 7.2.0, if that matters.

Comment: I agree that isn't an exact duplicate, but don't the answers to that question answer this one?

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't think so. They seem to concern Handcent, whatever it is.

Comment: Because Handcent is the solution, they mention that there is no way to avoid the smilies in the stock app.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Disable smileys in SMS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13569) anyway, but both are simply linked to the more useful question (useful as in, it provides answers) as that seems like the best solution. As @MatthewRead noted - and the first answer in the duplicate states - the reason Handcent is brought up repeatedly is because the answer to your question is simply "You can't".